# How display a Contentul image with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to display a single image which is stored on Contentful. This is my query to get the url and the title of the image :

```
contentfulAsset(title: {eq: "kevin"}) {
  file {
    url
    fileName
  }
}
```

I use the **gatsby-image** plugin but there is no explanation to know how to use this query to display a single image.

They only explain the situation with multiples images and a node...

```
{node.image[0].resolutions.src && (
  <Img
    style={{ margin: 0 }}
    resolutions={node.image[0].resolutions}
  />
)}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My first advice would be to always use the **GraphiQL** page while developing. it gives you an idea on how to use the query results on your Components.

http://localhost:8000/___graphql

Your query depends on how you want to display your image.

Suppose that you have stored an image with the field name `myImage` on `Asset` content model on **Contentful**.

### Display with HTML5 `<img />` tag

If you want to use a simple `<img />` tag

#### your query

```
contentfulAsset(title: { eq: "kevin"}}) {
  title
  file {
    url
  }
}
```

#### your component

```
// ...
const MyComponent = props => {
  const myImage = props.data.contentfulAsset;

  return <img src={myImage.file.url} alt={myImage.title} />
}
```

### Display with gatsby-image plugin

If you want to take benefit of the `gatsby-image` plugin, you first need to know if you want to use the `resolutions` or `sizes` child on your query.

See [gatsby-image documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#two-types-of-responsive-images) for more information.

Then you can use a query **Fragment** available with `gatsby-source-contentful`.

See https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#gatsby-source-contentful

#### your query

So let say we want to display a responsive image with a blur effect while loading, with `Webp` format:

```
contentfulAsset(title: { eq: "kevin"}}) {
  title
  sizes(quality: 100) {
    ...GatsbyContentfulSizes_withWebp
  }
}
```

> Note: by default, the `resolutions` and `sizes` quality are set to 50. That's why I set it to 100 in this query

#### your component

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  const myImage = props.data.contentfulAsset;

  return <Img sizes={myImage.sizes} alt={myImage.title} />
}
```

---

> Like most of official Gatsby plugins, you can find a very good example in the `examples` folder on the GitHub repository:
>
> https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-contentful

Comment: Thanks ! 

I'm having a issue : [screenshot](https://ibb.co/g66Vic)

**My query :**

`
contentfulAsset(title: {eq: "kevin"}) {
        file {
          url
          fileName
        }
      }
`

**My component**
`
const ImageKevin = props => {
  const Image = props.data.contentfulAsset.file;

  return <Img sizes={Image.sizes} alt={Image.title} />
}
`

Comment: It looks like `data` is `undefined`. It means that something is wrong with your graphql query. Could you please share your code on a fiddle or codepen ?

Comment: I found 2 issues in your code:
1) You don't pass any props to your `ImageKevin` props. The graphQL query will only pass props to your exported page Component.
2) you graphql query of the image must contains the `sizes` child node.

[Here is my modification suggestion](https://codepen.io/SebastienBelmon/pen/YLWjNx?editors=0010)

Can you give it a try ?

Comment: I'm tring to display a second image, but it's seems I can only use the contentfulAsset query juste one time... [screenshot](https://ibb.co/ii62yc) 
My code : [codepen](https://codepen.io/kevinfuret-the-animator/pen/LmRWjm?editors=0010)

Comment: You can but you have to rename your node query.
`imageKevin: contentfulAsset(title: { eq: "kevin}) { ### }` and then you use it with `data.imageKevin`

Comment: Actually, I don't know where I use the `data.imageKevin` inside `const ImageKevin = ({ image }) => {
  return <Img sizes={image.sizes} alt={image.title} />
}`

Comment: Use it outside your `ImageKevin` Component. When you pass the image props to it actually.